# Android Image view animation is slow

Tags: java, android, performance, android-animation

I am trying to apply multiple-animation for multiple image views at the same time. Below is the code snippet.

```
    final AnimatorSet animationSet = new AnimatorSet();
            for(int i=0;i<frame.getChildCount();i++){
                final ImageView vw = (ImageView) frame.getChildAt(i);

                animationSet.playTogether(
                        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(vw, "rotationY", 60),
                        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(vw, "scaleY", 0.8f),
                        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(vw, "x", 0)
                );
                animationSet.setDuration(600);
                animationSet.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(1.5f));
                animationSet.start();
```

this is applied to every item while swiping.

When i swipe on the screen images will animate. This animation is very slow when the image count increases. I have tried providing below

1.Adding Layer type and setting null while animation ended

2.Tried Setting hardwareaccelerated aattribute in Manifest

3.Tried setting large heap attribute in manifest

4.Added animation cache for items.

5.Tried running with high RAM devices.

is there any option to improve animation performance or any alternatives in android.?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use [ViewPropertyAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) .
Its probably the easiest way to animate Views and is usually pretty smooth. For your example it would be something like this :

```
vw.animate()
    .rotationY(60)
    .scaleY(0.8f)
    .setDuration(600)
    .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
```

Check the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) for all available methods.

EDIT : 
If multiple Animations at the same time are lagging, try using a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) it will take care of the Threading for you, and should make it smoother.
Something like this :

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

for(int i=0;i<frame.getChildCount();i++){
    final ImageView vw = (ImageView) frame.getChildAt(i);

     mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run () {
           vw.animate()
                .rotationY(60)
                .scaleY(0.8f)
                .setDuration(600)
                .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

           }
       });
    }
```

Comment: @A Honey Bustard - Thanks, this helps for one time animating. i am trying like scrolling images from right to left or vice versa, in which scrolling will be continuous. In that case, the animation is very slow. I have also tried converting image to bitmap and animated the canvas drawn view.. which is also slow.. any suggestion.?