# Adding a large number of views to the viewAnimator will slow down the program in android?

Tags: android, android-view

I have to add about 25-30 views to android `viewAnimator`, Adding this number of views to it will slow down the program?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the phone used, but in most cases yes.

This can help you [Android Image view animation is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35306742/android-image-view-animation-is-slow)

Comment: Thanks. When viewAnimator go to another view, previous view visility is  `GONE` or it set to `INVISIBLE`?

Comment: As far as i know is set to invisible

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: If it helped, consider marking the answer as acepted